# Xamarin Forms Shell ToolbarItem Not responding to Command Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am in the process of converting a Xamarin Forms non Shell app over to the Shell format. I have encountered an issue where a `ToolbarItem` defined on a `ContentPage` is not responding to the bound `Command` when it changes its executable status. I have verified this by adding standard buttons into the same page and have bound them to the same `Command` as per the below xaml.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Edit" Priority="1" Command="{Binding ToggleEditCommand}" Order="Primary"
                 Icon="{OnPlatform Android=ic_edit_white_24dp.png, UWP=Assets/Icons/ic_edit_dark_48dp.png}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Priority="2" Command="{Binding SaveItemCommand}" Order="Primary"
                 Icon="{OnPlatform Android=ic_save_white_24dp.png, UWP=Assets/Icons/ic_save_dark_48dp.png}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Copy" Priority="3" Command="{Binding CopyItemCommand}" Order="Secondary"
                 Icon="{OnPlatform Android=ic_content_copy_white_24dp.png, UWP=Assets/Icons/ic_content_copy_dark_48dp.png}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Delete" Priority="4" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}" Order="Secondary"
                 Icon="{OnPlatform Android=ic_delete_white_24dp.png, UWP=Assets/Icons/ic_delete_dark_48dp.png}"/>

</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="edit" Command="{Binding ToggleEditCommand}"/>
        <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveItemCommand}"/>
        <Button Text="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyItemCommand}"/>
        <Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <editviews:GameActionEditView IsVisible="{Binding IsVMInEditMode}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsVMInViewMode}" Grid.Row="1">
        <viewonly:GameActionView BindingContext="{Binding SelectedGameAction}"/>
    </Grid>
```

When I navigate to the page, it responds and updates the view model as expected, which in turn updates the various `Command` objects and the buttons, but not the `ToolbarItems` bound to the same `Command`. The below gif's don't display my attempts at clicking on the `ToolbarItem` to save, but I am doing so during the gap from typing 'effect' and pressing the save button.

this is on forms version 4.3.0.991211

Is there a known bug? Is there a workaround?

[image: ToolbarItemNotUpdating1]

[image: ToolbarItemNotUpdating2]

**EDIT: Viewmodel Code**

As requested, here is the ViewModel Code. Constructor:

```
public GameActionVM()//GameActionsViewModel gameActionsViewModel)
    {
        //_parentCollectionVM = ((App)Application.Current).viewModel._gamemActionsVM ?? null;
        _isVMInEditMode = false;
        _isVMInViewMode = true;
        ActionCosts = new ObservableCollection<ActionCost>();
        ToggleEditCommand = new Command(ToggleEditMode, CanToggleEditMode);
        CopyItemCommand = new Command(async () => await CopyItemAsync(), CanCopyItem);
        SaveItemCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveItemAsync(), CanSaveItem);
        DeleteItemCommand = new Command(async () => await DeleteItemAsync(), CanDeleteItem);
        ShowUserContentWarningCommand = new Command(async () => await ShowUserContenWarningAsync(), CanShowUserContentWarning);
        RePopulateReferenceTypesAsync();
    }
```

Propetychanged listener to call the Can Execute method

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Title":
            case "Effect":
            case "SelectedActionCost":
                HasUnsavedChanges = CheckForUnsavedChanges();
                SaveItemCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                break;
            case "IsVMInEditMode":
                IsVMInViewMode = !IsVMInEditMode;
                CopyItemCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                SaveItemCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                DeleteItemCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                ToggleEditCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                break;
        }
    }
```

And finally the Can Execute method for the save command;

```
protected override bool CanSaveItem()
    {
        if (!IsVMInEditMode) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title)) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Effect)) return false;
        if (Title.Length > 40) return false;
        if (Effect.Length > 1000) return false;
        if (SelectedActionCost == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

**EDIT 2: Repo link added **
I've managed to reproduce the issue in the Shell template straight out of Visual Studio (2019, v16.4.0). Repo can be found [on GITHUB](https://github.com/ExquisiteMonkey/ShellTest)

Comment: Can we see your VM code?

Comment: I want to see your VM code too. I can't reproduce this problem on my side. From the second gif, it seems the ToolbarItem has been disabled.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have added the parts of the view model I think are relevant, given the size of the post already. Let me know if you would like anything further to assist.

Comment: Toolbar item did response to the bound Command when it changes its executable status on my side. Can you please share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT As you mentioned you were able to get it to respond, I have been trying to dig around in my code assuming I must be doing something somewhere. One of the steps taken was to check the IsEnabled status immediately after the InitialiseComponent call and again after setting the viewmodel to the BindingContext. At both points, the property is false, and attempting to set these manually to true yields no results. Any suggestions? These previously (pre Shell) initialised as IsEnabled = true. I am going to try and produce a copy of the code, but it will likely take me a bit of time.

Comment: You can remove some unnecessary code when you test. I will check if you share a sample project.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I've added a link to a GitHub repo.

Comment: Ok, I just test the sample and found it only happens in Android side. If I change the default value of _state to true, it also works well. I will update you if I find any solution.

Comment: Also, someone has created an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8741).

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'm not set up for Ios, and UWP isn't complete, so could not see this myself. I have started following the issue you linked.

Comment: Yes, follow that issue to get the latest information.

Comment: @Lindsay The issue has been fixed in Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0, please update Xamarin.Forms to this version to fix the issue.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, After updating to the 4.4 stable build, the issue is still there. I have updated the ShellTest project hosted on Git, and am still experiencing the same problem. In fact, the button no longer updates per the property values when updating for XAML hot reload.